# Scala version warning for scala-java8-compat_2.12:0.8.0

Tags: scala, maven, compiler-warnings, scala-2.12

I am using scala 2.12.1 for a project built with maven but am getting version warnings like the one below:

```
[WARNING]  org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.12:0.8.0 requires scala version: 2.12.0
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
```

What can I do to get the versioning right here? From what I understand these are libraries scala itself brings in and not explicitly defined by me. I get the same for `xml` lib too.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of such warnings just add this to the `<configuration>` block of the `<maven-scala-plugin>` definition in your pom.xml:

```
<scalaCompatVersion>${scala.compat.version}</scalaCompatVersion>
```

And add `<scala.compat.version>2.12</scala.compat.version>` to the `<properties>` section.

---

These warnings may be safely discarded unless [major or minor](https://semver.org/) versions differ. As stated [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/binary-compatibility-of-scala-releases.html#concretely):

> We guarantee forwards and backwards compatibility of the "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.N.x" and "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.N.x" artifacts

---

Also, to find out how some library appeared in one's project dependencies, one can use:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
```